# Conditional CanCanCan Abilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I have a ClientServer that has many ClientApplications. I want users to only be able to destroy Servers that are associated with them. Every ClientApplication object has an application_owner_email that is matched against the current_user. If the emails match, they should have destroy permission for the associated Server. 
In the abilities.rb, I have the following

```
if user.has_role?(:application_owner)
 can :destroy, ClientServer.all.each do |server|
  server.client_applications.each do |app|
   app.application_owner_email == user.email
  end
end
```

But this isn't working. I have set up similar conditions. For instance, the below condition works fine:

```
can :destroy, ClientApplication.all.each do |app|
  app.application_owner_email == user.email
end
```

A user can only destroy ClientApplications where they are the application_owner.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that user can destroy a server if _all_ applications on that `server` are owned by them?

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable#each` returns object `self`, you probably want `.all?` or `.any?`:

```
can :destroy, ClientServer do |server|
  server.client_applications.all?{|app| app.application_owner_email == user.email }
end
```

Note that `all?` returns `true` for empty array.

Also note that abilities with blocks cannot generate scopes and are usually slower.